# Cast Error for Mongoose Populate Method

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have two collections with one, descriptions, that is the parent, with images, which is the child and makes a reference to the descriptions collection. Based on this hierarchy my collections are setup like so.

descriptions: (example document)

```
{
    "_id": "navy-blue",
    "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut consequat nunc sit amet massa congue pharetra. Aliquam pretium arcu nec velit accumsan, nec pellentesque mauris porttitor. Donec ultrices interdum mi, in viverra nulla posuere sit amet. Donec quis elit nibh. Cras condimentum aliquam ullamcorper. In blandit, turpis a aliquam laoreet, sapien nunc venenatis nisl, vel blandit massa massa non lacus. Cras tempor enim non consequat iaculis. Curabitur quis urna tellus. Nunc at mattis justo. Donec dolor velit, placerat ut co"
}
```

images: (reference is descriptions_id, example document)

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "55f0e2977f057f0d2f2ce548"
    },
    "pattern": "solid",
    "propercasePattern": "Solid",
    "color": "navy-blue",
    "propercaseColor": "Navy Blue",
    "imageUrl": "example.com/navy.jpg",
    "imageSource": "http://test.com/",
    "descriptions_id": "navy-blue"
}
```

As a result of this setup, I am trying to setup my route to look for a color and pattern that is selected and display all of the images documents that match, while displaying the description attached. This description on needs the color and not the pattern.

Here is my route: (error comes from doc.descriptions_id console log)

```
router.get('/:pattern/:color/result', function(req, res){

    console.log(req.params.color);

    Images.find( { pattern: req.params.pattern, color: req.params.color }).populate('descriptions_id').exec(function(err, image, doc){
        if (err) { console.log(err); }
        //console.log(image);
        console.log(doc.descriptions_id);
        res.render('pages/suit-result.hbs', {
            pattern : req.params.pattern,
            color : req.params.color,
            image : image
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the error message I get with my current setup:

```
[CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "navy-blue" at path "_id"]
  stack: 'Error\n    at MongooseError.CastError 
message: 'Cast to ObjectId failed for value "navy-blue" at path "_id"',
  name: 'CastError',
  kind: 'ObjectId',
  value: 'navy-blue',
  path: '_id' }
```

Why is it failing at that value, when in the mongoose documents it shows you that you should use a id naming convention as the reference point?

**UPDATE**

Descriptions model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var descriptionSchema = new Schema({
    color: String,
    body: String,
});

var Description = mongoose.model('Description', descriptionSchema);

module.exports = Description;
```

Images model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var imageSchema = new Schema({
    pattern: String,
    color: { type: String,  ref: 'Description'},
    imageName: String,
    imageUrl: String,
    imageSource: String
});

var Images = mongoose.model('Images', imageSchema);

module.exports = Images;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would seem that your schema defintions are not correct, or at least you have not overriden the default handling for `_id`. You also appear to be calling the wrong path with `.populate()` as your intended value should be "color".

Here is a sample:

```
var async = require('async'),
    mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema;

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');

var data = {
  "_id": "navy-blue",
  "body": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut consequat nunc sit amet massa congue pharetra. Aliquam pretium arcu nec velit accumsan, nec pellentesque mauris porttitor. Donec ultrices interdum mi, in viverra nulla posuere sit amet. Donec quis elit nibh. Cras condimentum aliquam ullamcorper. In blandit, turpis a aliquam laoreet, sapien nunc venenatis nisl, vel blandit massa massa non lacus. Cras tempor enim non consequat iaculis. Curabitur quis urna tellus. Nunc at mattis justo. Donec dolor velit, placerat ut co"
};


var descriptionSchema = new Schema({
  _id: String,
  body: String
},{ _id: false });

var imageSchema = new Schema({
  color: { type: String, ref: 'Description' },
  propercaseColor: String
});

var Description = mongoose.model('Description',descriptionSchema),
    Image = mongoose.model('Image',imageSchema);


async.series(
  [
    function(callback) {
      async.each([Description,Image],function(model,callback) {
        model.remove({},callback);
      },callback);
    },

    function(callback) {
      async.waterfall(
        [
          function(callback) {
            Description.create(data,callback);
          },
          function(desc,callback) {
            Image.create({
              "color": desc,
              "propercaseColor": "Navy Blue"
            },function(err) {
              callback(err);
            });
          }
        ],
        callback
      );
    },
    function(callback) {
      Image.find().populate('color').exec(function(err,doc) {
        console.log(doc);
        callback(err);
      });
    }
  ],
  function(err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    mongoose.disconnect();
  }
);
```

Which returns the populated object:

```
[ { _id: 56060d1812966d29622f8a04,
    color:
     { _id: 'navy-blue',
       body: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut consequat nunc sit amet massa congue pharetra. Aliquam pretium arcu nec velit accumsan, nec pellentesque mauris porttitor. Donec ultrices interdum mi, in viverra nulla posuere sit amet. Donec quis elit nibh. Cras condimentum aliquam ullamcorper. In blandit, turpis a aliquam laoreet, sapien nunc venenatis nisl, vel blandit massa massa non lacus. Cras tempor enim non consequat iaculis. Curabitur quis urna tellus. Nunc at mattis justo. Donec dolor velit, placerat ut co',
       __v: 0 },
    propercaseColor: 'Navy Blue',
    __v: 0 } ]
```

And of course without the `.populate()` it is just the value stored in "color" within the images collection:

```
[ { _id: 56060d5f81fff8356262d711,
    color: 'navy-blue',
    propercaseColor: 'Navy Blue',
    __v: 0 } ]
```

So make sure your schema is properly defined to the "ref" model and of course in the linked model that `_id` is both set to the correct type and of course that the configuration disables `ObjectId` creation and casting via `{ _id: false }`.

Comment: Hey @Blakes Seven, thanks for the thorough answer. I'm trying to craft up command line methods to make these updates to my documents rather then do async callbacks and create new documents. I don't plan on adding any new documents to my collections, but modify to make the reference correct. Based on this it doesn't seem like I can run `.update` because it doesn't change the `Id` of the record

Comment: I have also updated my question with my two model files, although I have been added documents from a .json file and not really utilizing these models with my routing. The model files have also been changed based on your suggested reference field. `descriptions_id` has been removed.

Comment: @cphill Mongoose and mongodb "require" the `_id` field as it is a the primary key. The point of the content here is that you follow it rather than make up your own approach, as this is the structure that works and the reason why trying anything different will not. The remainder of your comments talk about things outside of the scope of this question. If you have other questions then you [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). StckOverflow is for specific questions and answers, and not a threaded discussion board.

Comment: Understood and I will ask a different question. Thanks!